# Remove whole array in multi-dimensional array where indexOf != -1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array that looks a bit like this:

```
var basketData = [
  ["Image name","image_path", "image_long_path"],
  ["Image another name","image_path", "image_long_path"],
  ["Image different name","image_path", "image_long_path"],
]
```

I need to remove the whole sub-array where I match the first element, on click.

I have managed to write a function that identifies if the `imageName` exists at all in the sub-array:

```
function removeFromBasket(imageName) {
    console.log('Removing ' + imageName);
    for (i = 0; i < basketData.length; i++) {
        if (basketData[i].indexOf(imageName) != -1) {
            // it exists in the array
        } else {
            // it doesn't exist
 }
```

So the `index` will be returned as `0` if it exists, or `-1` if it doesn't. However, now I need to remove the sub-array where this index is identified. This is where I realise I've gone wrong.

Doing the following remove only the matched index in this array, which is silly because I already know that if it exists, it's going to be `0` as that's the only place this data is found:

```
basketData[i].splice(basketData[i].indexOf(imageName), 1);
```

So it only removes the first element of the sub-array, instead of removing the whole subarray.

So, **how can I remove the whole sub-array where `imageName` is found by iterating through the sub-array until I find a matching element?**

Comment: `basketData.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: Why are you using indexOf if you know in advance that element is the first one? `basketData[i][0] === imageName`

Comment: matched can be just one sub array or a few?

Comment: sidenote: why you use `indexOf` if you know that name in first element, so `basketData[i][0] === imageName` should be enough

Comment: can you provide expected output for your sample?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Within the filter callback, you can check the `indexOf` of the *whole* sub-array

```js
var imageName = "Image another name";
var basketData = [
  ["Image name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
  ["Image another name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
  ["Image different name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
];

// New function syntax! Supported in all modern browsers except for Safari
var result = basketData.filter(innerArray => innerArray.indexOf(imageName) == -1);

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id='p'></pre>
```

Comment: When using a stack snippet, I find it more useful to use `document.body.innerText = result;` to show the result in the snippet result area, rather than using `console.log()`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, good point. But then you get into the peculiarities of printing array items in a nice, readable, *array* format

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I'm assuming `result` returns the index of the sub-array? Therefore if it's in location `0` in the array, the following should remove it? `basketData.splice(result,1);` Except it doesn't, it just removes the index `0` from my sub-array. The sub-array remains.

Comment: @user1486133, here `result` already not have this item, you not need do splice

Comment: @Grundy I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: @user1486133, my answer takes a completely different approach to achieve what you needed. Instead of `splice` it uses the `filter` function. Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0cerqq4n/

Comment: @user1486133, i mean that code from answer already working, and return result that you want. Why you say that it not working for you?

Comment: @user1486133, `result` is the array without the sub-array with the image name

Comment: @user1486133, try see this output, are you really want some other output?

Answer (score 0):

```
var basketData = [
      ["Image name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
      ["Image another name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
      ["Image different name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
    ]

function removeFromBasket(imageName) {
    console.log('Removing ' + imageName);
    for (i = basketData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (basketData[i].indexOf(imageName) != -1) {
            basketData.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

when we splice inside a for loop, we are ruining the index that we are using to reference the other elements in the array. We can just reverse the for loop, using -- rather than ++.
Because We start at the top, none of the values get upset when you start permanently deleting and shifting values across

Comment: I also can't get this working. It just removes the index matching element from the sub-array, not from the parent array.

Comment: @user1486133, are you try it? what you mean when say `subarray`?

Comment: @Grundy the sub-arrays are the arrays within the main array.

Comment: @user1486133, so, why you say that this solution and AmmarCSE's solution not work for you?

Comment: @Grundy yes, none of the solutions here remove the sub-array. They remove the [1] element in the last array.

Comment: @user1486133, are you try it? they make from `basketData`, that at start array with 3 elements, array with two elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94602/discussion-between-grundy-and-user1486133).

Answer (score 0):

```
var basketData = [
      ["Image name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
      ["Image another name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
      ["Image different name", "image_path", "image_long_path"],
     ]


var deleteBasket = function (name) {
    for (i=0; i<basketData.length; i++){
            if (basketData[i][0] === name){
                  basketData.splice(i--,1);
                }
            else {

                }
        };
    }
 deleteBasket("Image another name");
 console.log(basketData);
```